# ERC721 `safeTransfer()` chain of events

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721, nft

When examining `OpenZeppelin's` library of contracts for `ERC721` Tokens, you'll find that all tolled, there are literally *five* flavors of the `transfer` method, as follows:

1. `transferFrom(from, to, tokenId)` - where this function then internally calls
2. `_transfer(from, to, tokenId)`

Then there's:
3. `safeTransferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId)` - where this function internally calls the
4. `safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, "")` - which has that additional `bytes array` argument, and which then calls
5. `_safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, _data)` - which - like `#1` also then internally calls

`_transfer(from, to, tokenId)`

So basically, no matter which of these you're calling, all roads eventually lead to the `_transfer(from, to, tokenId)` method, which is where the real business of transferring takes place.

I do understand wanting in general to have that additional `safe` flavor for `transfer`, but...

1. why have so many of them? Specifically,
2. what sort of `data` might one pass when using `safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, _data)`? Like what's a good example for that? (Asking cause I've yet to come across a case where that one was used)
3. if you choose to go with option # 3 (`safeTransferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId)`), you will literally end up calling a total of 4 functions (because of how they're internally "chained" together) in order to accomplish what you want - which I think means paying 4 times as much `gas` (maybe not exactly 4x, but certainly more than you would for calling just one function) - so why/when would you actually want to do that?

Would love any insights into all this.